# Create another dataframe based on an existing dataframe based on a column value in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame, df in R:

```
ID    Name    Class
3     John    3A
32    Fanny   7B
12    Greg    3A
```

and I want to segregate the data, by creating a new dataframe for all rows with Class value 3A which means the new dataframe would be:

```
ID    Name    Class
3     John    3A
12    Greg    3A
```

Since rows above have value 3A in the Class column.

I tried the following:

```
df_2 <- df[df["Class"]=="3A"]
```

But the df_2 dataframe does not seem to appear.

Comment: you are missing a comma there. try `df[df["Class"]=="3A",]`

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the python and R

Here is the correct code:

```
df_2 <- df[df$Class=="3A", ]
df_2
```